# Get Top 5 Data Based on Total Sales from 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I have table 'sales' and data like this scheme :

```
name | Amount| Month
user a      100     1
user b      240     1
user c      120     1
user a      200     2
user b      130     2
user c      240     2
```

And User Table like this :

```
User    |  Pict
user a    user_a.jpg
user b    user_a.jpg
user c    user_a.jpg
```

How to get TOP 5 user based on Total Sales every month, I've tried using query like this , but there's always showed not properly:

```
SELECT User, 
   SUM(amount) AS total_sales 
 FROM sales 
 WHERE MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 12
 GROUP BY User
 ORDER BY total_sales DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

And the result should be :

```
user_a.jpg | User a | 300
user_b.jpg | User b | 370
user_c.jpg | User c | 360
```

So the order must be  : B,C,A cuz based on top total sales.

But output always like this :

```
user_a.jpg | User a | 300
user_a.jpg | User b | 370
user_a.jpg | User c | 360
```

First column always user_a.jpg

Comment: Your expected output and current output are same in the question. Maybe you need to edit and fix that part. Now, your query should be doing exactly what you need; so you need to setup a fiddle showcasing your claim!

Comment: Your question is a mess. Given that your pictures table only contains 'user_a.jpg' how can the output contain 'user_c.jpg'? Your query returns two result columns, yet you report three. I guess the root of your problem is the same sloppy behaviour.

Comment: Sorry if you can't get my message very well I've try my best for this :(

Answer (score 1):

You're half way there. Join your query with users table like so:

```
SELECT users.user, users.pict, total_sales
FROM (
    SELECT name, SUM(Amount) AS total_sales
    FROM sales
    WHERE Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY total_sales
    LIMIT 5
) AS user_sales
INNER JOIN users ON user_sales.name = users.user
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```

You seem to have mixed up the column names; you must revise the above query accordingly.